# "He made me down" sounds ok to say "He made me sad"? If not, why so?

Tags: adjectives, sentence-patterns, causative-verbs, verb-patterns

I'm a newbie to this forum and I've been wondering if the sentence below is gramatically correct, and if not, pls explain the reason linguistically.

(I'm not a native English speaker.)

> He made me down.

To my knowledge, "He MADE me sad, He LET me down, He GOT me down" are all gramatically perfect.

And, these sentences in all have
 patterns. Then, why is it wrong or does it sound unnatural saying "He made me down" to imply
 "He mad me sad"? (I've never heard "He made me down")

Comment: He made me ‘down’ is an incomplete sentence. He made me go down? He made me feel down? He made me push down?

Comment: Was this a  spoken or written utterance? Was it taped? Or did you actually hear someone say it in person or on live TV. There are many questions one could ask about your question.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *to make* normally doesn't take *down* as an adverb (and I cannot think of an instance where it does). However, *to feel* does take *down* as an adverb, so "He made me feel down" is probably what you are looking for.

There are no rules for what adverbs any particular verb can take. It is just a matter of common (and accepted) usage.

Comment: It's a very legitimate question because of the weird way we treat the word "down". It is nominally an adverb, but is it really an adverb in "I'm feeling down"? It really is an adjective in this sentence -- "I'm feeling" is a state-of-being when you say "I'm feeling down".  You don't say  "I fell sickly."  If you're looking for a rule, the closest might be that "down" meaning  "depressed" or "sad" is used mainly in conjunction with state-of-being verbs.

Comment: @Blaise Actually *sickly* **is** an adjective.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Quite so. I should have in any case said "You don't say 'I feel illy.''"